Accessing and using files in a volume from multi-container apps
I am new to using Docker and would really appreciate any opinions on how to set this up/if Docker is appropriate for solving this problem. What I would like to do is to have the situation where multiple containers act as individual farms, that sell cows to a ‘market’ on  a ‘market day’ as part of a larger daily ‘farm-life’ simulation.
I have a simple python script that creates a .txt files of random sold animals, and these are written into a volume – and what I need is either another container/something else to do is keep track of how many ‘farms’ have written their files and sold the cows to the market, then once all farms have sold their selected cows to the market, send a file back to each farm to allow the simulation to continue with other parts.
I also ideally need a way for this to happen multiple times, so for example the simulation would run for 365 days and cows would be sold and bought from the volume every week, so the containers need wait for each other before progressing. I’d be grateful for any ideas on how to set this up/if it is possible.
Here is my current code set up.
Dockerfile
FROM python:3.8
RUN mkdir /app
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "animals.py"]

market.Dockerfile
FROM python:3.8
RUN mkdir /app
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
CMD ["python3"]

Docker compose file
version: '2'
services:
  farm_1:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
    - "5000"
    volumes:
      - market_volume:/app/data/cows_to_sell
  the_market:
    build:
      dockerfile: market.Dockerfile
    ports:
        - "4000"
    volumes:
        - market_volume:/app/data/cows_to_sell
    depends_on:
      - farm_1
volumes:
  market_volume:


Script that generates random sold animals
animals.py
import random
def generate_farm_name():
    farm_name = "Farm_" + str(random.choice(range(0,100)))
    return(farm_name)

farm_name = generate_farm_name()

market_name = './data/cows_to_sell/' + farm_name + '.txt'

f = open(market_name, "w+")

animals = ['cow A', 'cow B', 'cow C', 'cow D', 'cow E', 'cow F']

def write_animals(farm_name, market_name):
    selected = random.choice(animals)
    with open(market_name, 'a') as f:
        f.write(farm_name + " " + selected + "\n")


write_animals(farm_name, market_name)

Currently this code writes a file into the volume for 5 farm containers using docker-compose up --build --scale farm_1=5, I think the 'market' container would count the files in the volume somehow, and then send a file back to each farm to allow it to progress with the simulation, but I haven't found a way to get this to work at all yet.

Shared files aren't going to be the right approach for this.  I might look into setting up an HTTP-based setup, where the simulations can send HTTP POST requests to the central server to perform the "sell" actions, and HTTP GET requests to retrieve the next state.  A messaging-based system like RabbitMQ can also work well here, where the simulations send their actions on a dedicated topic to the market, and the market sends back state either to individual simulation topics or via a broadcast.

(If you're more exploring and don't mind learning a new language, I've been enjoying using Elixir for this kind of thing.  In particular its "process" model maps well to what you're describing: the individual simulations and the central market can be processes, and the runtime would support running the application either in a single OS executable or distributed across several hosts.)
